# What is the best way to get database name use java metadata

Tags: java, spring, database, jdbc, metadata

In my application using different databases (postgres, mssql, oracle ...). What is the best way to get database name use metadata. I was trying to use this approach:

```
try (final Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()) {
    final DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
    final String databaseName = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(connection.getMetaData().getURL(), "/");
```

It works in this case:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/2022_2
```

But in this case it doesn't work:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=test_mssql;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using [Connection#getCatalog()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getCatalog()) for your case.

Please see the following example below:

```java
try (final Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()) {
    String databaseName = connection.getCatalog();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```